# power bi budget target sales

Tags: powerbi, dax

Need to calculate budget for working days, but I've just found how to calculate for the days in that particular month in this website https://blog.enterprisedna.co/the-ultimate-budget-allocation-formula-for-power-bi-analysis/#respond.

This solution though, is not exactly what I need since I need to keep just working days and then take into account the working days that have passed until today.

I have a Sales table with sales every day, a calendar table, and a budget table with budget for every month, but not at a day level like the sales table.

I used this formula from the website Enterprise DNA adapted to my table, but need to keep just working days and then take into accounts the working days that have passed until today.

budget allocation =
VAR DAYINCONTEXT= COUNTROWS('calendar')
VAR DAYSINMONTH= CALCULATE(COUNTROWS('calendar'), ALL('calendar'), VALUES('calendar'[Year Month]))
VAR CURRENTMONTH= SELECTEDVALUE('calendar'[MonthYear])
VAR MONTHLYBUDGETAMOUNTS=
CALCULATE([total budget], TREATAS(VALUES('calendar'[MonthYear]), 'pressupostos'[MonthYear]))
RETURN
IF(OR(HASONEVALUE('calendar'[Date]), HASONEVALUE('calendar'[Year Month])),
DIVIDE(DAYINCONTEXT, DAYSINMONTH, 0)* MONTHLYBUDGETAMOUNTS,
[total budget])

Answer (score 0):

Why not just have a column in your Calendar table whether a day is a working day? then you can just use CALCULATE( COUNTROWS('Calendar'),'Calendar'[WorkingDay]=True) or something like that.

Then once you get the count of Workingdays per month, you just divide the monthly total by that.

Comment: Hello,

Many thanks for your answer. I already have this field in my calendar table, but what they are asking me for is kind of a rule of three or estimation of if at this pace the budget will be met at the end of the month. Don't know if I explain correctly. Thanks again

Comment: Maybe this doesn't directly answer your question, but how about a running total for budget and another for actual and then put them both on the same line graph? Then you'd see the trend of the two and see if the actuals are keeping up with the budget.

Comment: I think it's complicated because there are so many regions, products and so on that bosses ask for kind of a grid format. Many thanks